# Identify first iteration in for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'd like to iterate through a list of items and get the current iteration number. is there an easy way do this?

This is my (example) loop:

```
loopit <- c('happ','goof','funk')
str <- ''
for (l in loopit){
  print(paste0(l,'y'))
}
```

It's easy to build an iteration counter manually:

```
i <- 1
for (l in loopit){
  if(i==1){
    print(paste0('so ',l,'y!!!'))
  }else{
    print(paste0(l,'y'))
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Is there a more elegant, more direct way to get the current iteration number?

Comment: You could use `seq_along` like `for (i in seq_along(loopit)) {
  if (i==1) { print(paste0('so ',loopit[i],'y!!!')) }
  else {  print(paste0(loopit[i],'y')) }
}` but this may not as elegant as you may want.

Comment: Why loop? `c(paste0("so", loopit[1], "y!!!"), paste0(loopit[2:length(loopit)], "y"))`

Comment: Thanks for the seq_along - hint!!! and yes you're right, why looping in this silly example. but it's only an example for a more general problem. Is there no direct way to get the current iteration number while looping over a list?

Comment: `seq_along(loopit)` is same as `seq(loopit)` is same as `1:3`

Comment: If you need the index inside the loop, you should loop over the indices. Otherwise, there is no (efficient and reliable) way to get the index.

Comment: Thanks Roland for the clarification!!! It's a pity that a such a nice implementation of list-looping lacks such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific example you do not necessary need to know the number of iteration. Maybe it is the same also for your real problem. See the example.

```
foo <- function(x) {
  print(paste0('so ', head(x, 1), 'y!!!'))
  for (l in tail(x, -1)) print(paste0(l, 'y'))
}

foo(loopit)
```

Comment: thanks for your share. As mentioned above, for this example you would not need the current iteration. It's for illustrative purposes only. I need the solution in a more complex context

Comment: Do you really need to know the iterator in your complex context? You can always do one procedure for the first element and different process (for loop, for example) for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for (l in loopit){
  if(l==loopit[1]){
    print("first iteration")
  }
}
```